# In MYSQL - Select up to a certain value in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I searched for a solution since a few weeks, but however could not really solve problem: Is it possible to select only a few rows until or up to a certain value, which could repeating itself further down my table?
I think, an example can be very useful:

```
Type |  OBID    | RECID
5    | T-000032 | 5637637  
1    | T-123456 | 5637636 
1    | T-789123 | 5637635  
2    | T-123456 | 5637634
2    | T-789123 | 5637633 
1    | T-221133 | 5637628 
2    | T-221133 | 5637612
```

Here a little example:
This section of my table will always start with Type 5 followed by a couple of rows with Type 1. I only need this special "group" of rows with Type 1 since the first row with type 2 appears.
I would not be attracted to any other row with Type 1 - only this ones:

```
1  | T-123456 | 5637636 
1  | T-789123 | 5637635
```

Quasi only this rows with Type 1 which are between
the first row with Type 5 and 
the first row with Type 2.

I hope, you could help me. 
Thank you very very much.

Chrissy

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  In general, this is a gaps and islands problem.

Comment: A table doesn't have an "order" to it, so you will need to find a better criterion than "followed by". Is the `RECID` column ascending and does it provide that order for "later" ?

Comment: @Corion:  The original table, I would like to use, creates for every response a row with different information including a recid with descending order.

Comment: @Corion: It is possible, that several users book at the same time. So it is not possible only to select on this column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels like a gaps and islands problem, but in this case you just want a single island.  One approach is to use subqueries to find:

- The highest `RECID` value where `Type=1`.  This represents the
  *inclusive* upper bound of the island.
- The highest `RECID` value where `Type!=1`, *and* where the `RECID`
  value is also *less* than the above `RECID` value.  This serves as
  the *exclusive* lower bound of the island.

Here is a working query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE Type = 1 AND RECID > (SELECT MAX(RECID) FROM yourTable
                            WHERE Type <> 1 AND RECID < (SELECT MAX(RECID) FROM yourTable
                                                         WHERE Type = 1)) AND
                   RECID <= (SELECT MAX(RECID) FROM yourTable WHERE Type = 1)
ORDER BY
    RECID DESC;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: I checked it. There are some more rows, I did not need. But also work on it!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below for mysql version less than 8.0

```
 select * from
    (SELECT 
        @row_number:=CASE
            WHEN @Type = PType THEN @row_number + 1
            ELSE 1
        END AS num,
        @Type:=Type as PType,
        Type,
        OBID,RECID
    FROM
        tablename order by type,RECID desc
    )X where num in (1,2)
```

OR You can use row_number() in case mysql version 8.0+

```
select * from 
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by  type order by recid desc) as rn
from tablename
)X where rn in (1,2)
```